# What's the best way to handle unfinished items in an agile sprint branch?

Tags: svn, version-control, agile

If you work in an agile manner and have a branch for each sprint and also have policy that only finished and tested items can go back to the trunk, how do you best handle unfinished items?

Should the branch be kept alive and renamed into the new sprint branch and continue to work on these issues there? What if these issues should not be part of the upcoming sprint?

**Update**:

After answers from Alex Pereira among others I feel that I have miss-phrased my question, or rather misunderstood my own thoughts. I don't mean one branch per sprint. Rather one branch per release/feature set. And since that branch can continue to live the initial problem is actually non existent.

Combine that with feature branches and the issue with unfinished items becomes even easier to handle.

I do want to note that although developing towards the trunk (or any other predetermined branch) and then marking releases along the way is a feasable way that I have used before, I want a system that can scale from 1 to 100's of developers with minimal changes being needed. Thus there need to be ONE branch considered the stable one which done stuff goes into and there could be several parallel ones for different teams to work on features at the same time without interfering each other.

The ideas I had to facilitate all of this before I formulated like this

[image]

Comment: I would recommend keeping the plans (the sprint definition du jour) separate from the version control system for your deliverables. Use something like a ticketing system to communicate between the two. Let the developers name their branches whatever makes sense under this regime - ticket42 or asyncdns rather than 2012-03

Comment: Oh, and that doesn't mean you can't have a "sprint" branch as well. Developers could branch off that and sync occasionally to their own branches.

Comment: @triplee that makes sense to me

Comment: The question doesn't have to be seen as a sprint actually. It could just as well be a branch that has some done features but one or two that is underway. But the done issues has to be merged down to the mainline for release right now and not wait for the other issues to become complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure your setup is the most optimal here. I'm on a shop where we also do Agile, and we do not branch per Sprint, we rather branch it out per Release. I think it is unnecessary to have Sprint branches, when you could, in fact branch by Release and apply Labels if you wish for each Sprint. I also not not agree with the other comments where they suggest to let developers created their own branch, you are asking for a mess there.

In your case though, since you are already using that setup, I would say that you carry over the "hang over" to the next Sprint branch, and merge the current Sprint branch back to the Trunk. If the developers already started working on the current Sprint branch, then either move the code manually or do a baseless merge (if your source control allows it) to the next Sprint branch.

**Update 4/17/2012 12:43PM:**

We had a lot of discussions here at my job in regards to this. Basically, we have three agile teams working on three distinctive products, two .NET and one VB6 (legacy).

We wanted to figure out a standard way for all our teams to work on, and this is what we came up with - maybe it can help you:

Folder/Branching structure:

- **Development** (*branched off main - will contain release branches for future development - aways updated by changes in Main - only merges into Main when is time for release and code passes initial acceptance testing*)

  - Release 1
  - Release 2
- **Main**  (*this is the main trunk - contains relatively stable, release candidate code - where final builds are created*)
- **Release** (*branched off main when release approved by QA - never updated by changes is Main - Only gets updated by Service Packs to address critical defects or urgent enhancements, then changes are merged back into main*)

  - Release 1

    - Service Pack 1
    - Service Pack 2
  - Release 2

Comment: +1. A common theme in Agile is "all developers commit to the trunk". ie you don't have branches for your day-to-day dev work. This only really works for small teams, where people aren't going to tread on each others toes, but a branch for each sprint won't solve that problem. This site has some interesting thoughts on the topic: http://daveonscm.blogspot.co.uk/

Comment: Working in several large and smaller agile focused development companies I have to say that everyone submitting to single branch is a nightmare. Doesn't take many people before they "start stepping on toes". One branch per team and perhaps per sprint/feature after that and keep the stable stuff in trunk is my preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

Personally if the unfinished work is not to be carried over into the next sprint I would throw away the unfinished work.

Comment: To clarify it SHOULD be continued in the future. But prehaps not in the sprint immediately following this one.